# Why are nginx configuration files read-only on FreeBSD?

Tags: nginx, file-permissions, freebsd

After installing Nginx on FreeBSD 8.3 from ports, the configuration files in /usr/local/etc/nginx all have read-only permissions. Is there a reason for this? Am I not supposed to edit them? Or can I safely ignore that fact and modify them anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use nginx (and therefore don't use the port), but looking at the port it does the "standard" thing of copying the `dist` files over as the "live" files for a fresh install.
The maintainer specified the `-p` flag in doing this, which preserves the file mode, so the resulting "live" files are read-only.

There is no reason you can't make these files writeable by a specific user/group, or just edit them as root and ignore the lack of write permissions.

---

If you think this behavior is undesirable you should [file a PR](http://www.freebsd.org/send-pr.html) - it would be a pretty easy thing for the port maintainer to change.
Chances of getting it changed go up dramatically if you provide a patch (the offending file in the port is `pkg-plist`, and more information on how that file works can be found in [The Porter's Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/).)